# Good practices to organize attributes in a class?

Tags: java, attributes

I have in my class many parameters, many of which are related with each others.

First, I had something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int[] filterA = {4,40};
    private int filterAPasses = 3;

    private String dataFilePath = "...";
    private int dataChannels = 4;
    private int dataFreq = 300;

    private int[] timeRange = {30,40};
}
```

Well, I wasn't really satisfied, not easily readable in the declarations themselves, neither very handy to use , because I had many `filterA[0]` where I had to remember the meaning of index `0`, and index `1`.

So instead of that, I did :

```
public class MyClass {
    private interface filterA {
        int left = 4;
        int right = 40;
        int passes = 4;
    }

    private interface dataFile {
        String path = "...";
        int channels = 4;
        int frequency = 300;
    }

    private interface timeRange {
        int from = 30;
        int to = 40;
    }
}
```

which is way better, and allows me to do nice things such as `filterA.left`, or even adding javadoc to `left`

But somehow I feel bad to use `interface` to do that. Is that a *good* way ? are there better practices for such things ?

### Edit:

Okay, I was completely wrong since I didn't know that using `interface` those parameters will be final. 
It definitely isn't a good way. So what is a good way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested classes if you feel this is clearer.

```
public class MyClass {
    static class FilterA {
        int left = 4;
        int right = 40;
        int passes = 4;
    }
    private final FilterA filterA = new FilterA();

    static class DataFile {
        String path = "...";
        int channels = 4;
        int frequency = 300;
    }
    private final DataFile dataFile = new DataFile();

    private interface TimeRange {
        int from = 30;
        int to = 40;
    }
    private final TimeRange timeRange = new TimeRange();
}
```

or just use comments and meaningful names. (My preference)

```
public class MyClass {
    // fliter settings
    private int filterALeft = 4;
    private int filterARight = 40;
    private int filterAPasses = 3;

    // data path attributes
    private String dataFilePath = "...";
    private int dataChannels = 4;
    private int dataFreq = 300;

    // time range
    private int timeRangeFrom = 30;
    private int timeRangeTo = 40;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with nested classes. I like to namespaced-like things :)

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach won't work: all fields in your interfaces are `final`, you won't be able to change any value (use classes instead of interfaces if you want to use the fields like in the first example).

The names in your second example aren't good practise: interface names shall start with a capital, (non-static) field names with a non-capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You should create Constants as follows,

```
public class FilterA {
  public static final int LEFT = 4;
  public static final int RIGHT = 40;
  public static final int PASSES = 4; 
}
```

And different class for other type, each class will probably in separate file, and you can access above values as follows,

```
FilterA.LEFT
```

As "LEFT" is whole capital it is quite understandable that it is constant and you just want to use that. If you want to modify them you can remove final.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But the problem is, I don't want these values to be constant/final

Comment: Then remove final as I stated, implementing different class files would separate your logic and you can have different code in different files.

Comment: You can go with your first approach

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions !
I think I will go with nested classes as suggested by Peter L, as separated files would mean many more files for really tiny stuff without much logic inside

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use interfaces for defining constants, this is common antipattern as you can read from Effective Java (2nd edition), item 19. Interfaces should be only used to define types, not constants.

The answer Rahul gave is more a correct way. You may want to put a private constructor in `FilterA` to avoid the possibility of instantiate that class.

If you want, you can define accessor methods in the interface (getFilter - for example). This is what interfaces are made for (defining behaviour, not implementation).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit subjective, but imho, you'd do better to go further and actually create classes for your data clumps, and have your class fields be references to instances of these classes instead of the primitives you have now.